# C++ pointer to struct returned from function causes access violation

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new with C++. I use Visual Studio. My debug build works as intended, but the release build crashes with  Access violation.
The struct:

```
struct GeneticData
{
    int NumberOfIdDataPairs;
    char** IdBuffer;
    char** DataBuffer;
};
```

IdBuffer is an array of char arrays of 20 chars, Databuffer is an array of chars array of 102 chars.
The function which returns the pointer:

```
GeneticData* LoadData(FILE* dataFilePtr) //dataFilePtr is valid in the function
{
    char* result = NULL;
    int fileLine = 0;
    GeneticData geneticData = *new GeneticData();

    geneticData.NumberOfIdDataPairs = *new int;
    geneticData.IdBuffer = new char*[gSizeOfBuffer];
    geneticData.DataBuffer = new char*[gSizeOfBuffer];

    for (int i = 0; i < gSizeOfBuffer; i++)
    {
        geneticData.IdBuffer[i] = new char[gSizeOfId];
        geneticData.DataBuffer[i] = new char[gSizeOfData];
    }

    do
    {
        result = fgets(geneticData.IdBuffer[fileLine], gSizeOfId, dataFilePtr);
        fgets(geneticData.DataBuffer[fileLine], gSizeOfData, dataFilePtr);
        fileLine++;
    } while (result != NULL && fileLine < gSizeOfBuffer);

    if (result != NULL)
        geneticData.NumberOfIdDataPairs = fileLine;
    else
        geneticData.NumberOfIdDataPairs = fileLine - 1;

    return &geneticData;
}
```

The gSizeofBuffer is the number of id/data pairs, it's value is 1.000.000 at the moment.
Inside the function everything is all right, I can acces the values of the id/dataBuffer. The issue arises in the function which calls my LoadData function.

```
GeneticData geneticData;
geneticData = *LoadData(dataFilePtr);
//acces violation, geneticData contained invalid values
```

With `cout << geneticData.DataBuffer[1]` the debugger stopped here (post mortem debugging):
[image]

With `cout << geneticData.DataBuffer[1][0]` the debugger stopped at this line. In the actual algorithm which analyses the content of DataBuffer the debugger stops like in the case of cout << `geneticData.DataBuffer[1][0]`.
I allocated the memory of the GeneticData struct as dynamic memory, I do not understand why is the pointer invalid after the LoadData function returns it.

Comment: _"I am new with C++"_ Then it's time to learn the 1st and foremost rule: **Don't use pointers, unless you're absolutely sure you'll need them!**.

Comment: This is not the problem but: `geneticData.NumberOfIdDataPairs = *new int;` That's a memory leak. Just say `= 0`.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the NumberOfIdDataPairs too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
GeneticData geneticData = *new GeneticData();
```

This monstrosity dynamically allocates an object, uses that to copy-initialise a local variable, and then throws away the only pointer to it, causing a memory leak.

```
return &geneticData;
```

This returns a pointer to a local variable, which is destroyed before the caller can do anything with it; leading to your error.

Perhaps you want to return the dynamic object (remembering to delete it when you've finished using it):

```
GeneticData * geneticData = new GeneticData();
//...
return geneticData;
```

or perhaps you want to return an object by value:

```
GeneticData LoadData(FILE* dataFilePtr)
{
    GeneticData geneticData;
    //...
    return geneticData;
}
```

but you should do yourself a favour and stop messing around with pointers and `new`. Use `std::vector` for the buffers.

Comment: plus one for "monstrosity" :)

Comment: Thank you, I won't use pointers then. Also I switch the arrays to vectors.

Answer (score 5):

Your're returning a pointer to a temporary structure:

```
GeneticData geneticData = *new GeneticData(); // memoryleak: copies from dynamic memory into local
...
return &geneticData; // returns address of local memory
```

If you want to initialise a local structure write:

```
GeneticData geneticData; // calls the default constructor GeneticData() to initialise geneticData
```

Note that `geneticData` is only valid until the end of scope and so is an address to that variable!

If you need dynamic memory write:

```
GeneticData* pGeneticData = new GeneticData(); // allocates dynamic memory (new), calls the default constructor and assigns the memory address to the pointer pGeneticData
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace

```
GeneticData geneticData = *new GeneticData();
```

by

```
GeneticData* geneticData = new GeneticData(); // we define a pointer now
```

and

```
return &geneticData;
```

by

```
return geneticData; // return the pointer
```

But try to avoid using raw pointers unless you really know what you're doing.